# Can't manage to succesfully UV unwrap house to get aligned brick textured walls

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've started learning blender a few weeks ago and my desire is to model and render a brick house. I've followed a lot of tutorials on modelling and texturing. However, I can't manage to successfully line up the the brick texturing at the corners of the walls and at the windows as you might be able to see in the images I've added. I've tried to look up as much tutorials on UV-unwrapping but I keep bumping into the problem of lining up the bricks the right way.

I have added my blender model as well, I guess I have made mistakes with the seams and such. Could anyone help me and show me what I'm doing wrong? I'm very eager to learn :)

Kind regards,

Tomas

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6mA8yxW9pLEOS03QlM1eG8xWVU)

[image]

Comment: I would show you if you re-upload your file but before you save it go to File->External Data->Pack into.blend.

That way I dont get missing textures when I download the file.

Comment: you sure? still getting missing textures.

Answer (score 3):

Found that wrapping the UV map around the edge is the easiest way to get the bricks to line up. You just need to concentrate on the sides. Generally a sill covers the bottom layer and on the top - you can cheat more.

[image]

The image above shows the normal map which is used later to bump the texture...

[image]

...and this shows another building with rounded brick corners.

Some textures I made from baking walls of mesh bricks. Others I drew and composed in Gimp. You can see some of the trials [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?390640-Another-brick-in-the-wall) on the BlenderArtists thread.

**Update:** First step is to make sure your seams are marked for the unwrap - <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> if you haven't done that already. (You can see them marked red and just in the corners.) Then <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap. I use *Project from View* as I think it's the quickest to get neat UV's, and then just scale ...

[image: Project from View]

Select the recessed edges and scale them on the X axis in the UV editor...

[image: UV scaling]

These are the active buttons in the UV editor...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read both the topic you linked and the locked topic. From those topics I understood that you first tried the approach of making buildings brick by brick instead of planes which were texturised later on, because you found that using a texture didn't give enough dept on and in between the bricks. Later on you did use textures, how did you manage to get enough dept in the end?

Furthermore, I don't fully understand your answer above, though it is what I'm looking for. Especially how the vertical Sill (I believe it's called?) lines the bricks up perfectly.

Comment: Updated above - hope that makes it clearer. Depth in texture is created with bump maps - like the purplish bricks in the first image. It fakes depth but does not work well everywhere - like corner edges. That is maybe a topic for a new question though...