# Setting up UV direction

Tags: uv

I have created a hallway in Blender, and then I applied "Smart Unwrap":
[image]
The unwrap doesn't look absolutely perfect, but I thought it would do the job.

Then I exported the model as an fbx and imported it into Unity.
In Unity, I applied a material to it which has a texture assigned.

For some walls it looks fine, but for some walls, the direction of the UV map is changed for some reason, and the texture doesn't look right:

[image]

How could I set up the "direction" of the UVs in Blender and not just hope that it will work out alright (which it obviously doesn't)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use unwrap with `project from view` since your object is perpendicular, with view from specified angle and orthogonal view as well.

Comment: @Hikariztw Could you perhaps elaborate on what I should do to make that work? When I'm in side-view, it unwraps the side-view. How could I get the rest to get unwrapped, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Sure UVW Map (with UVW Box Map) to unwrap my architecture, it works great:

[How to UV unwrap a wall to get a consistent texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102335/how-to-uv-unwrap-a-wall-to-get-a-consistent-texture)

Answer (score 1):

When you do Smart UV Project you can generate UVs with islands.  Then you can select the pieces that need to be rotated and rotate them by pressing R 90 Enter.  You can also scale the pieces generated by pressing R 90 Enter.