# How do I match the UV map with the image used as texture

Tags: texturing, baking

How can I make the UV map coincide with the image used as texture 
(see image below) and apply it to the material of the model?
I seem to have a confusing UV map.

[image: Image[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjT0t.jpg)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102335/how-to-uv-unwrap-a-wall-to-get-a-consistent-texture/102337#102337

Comment: It's not a case of anything working I'm just baffled with some of the tutorials on how to apply and bake textures to the model (that includes normal, bump and AO)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for tutorials is considered off topic here, just use google instead. If you could rephrase your question to focus on the issue instead, and show us what you have tried and where you're stuck it would be great.

Comment: I do not understand this part: "which I have created in Materialize". What is *materialize*? Or is it a spelling error? It would also help if you added what rendering engine you want to use, cycles or eevee or the older blender .internal

Answer (score 0):

you can manually reposition the vertices of the UV map so that it matches with the mesh.

Select a vertex, press <kbd>L</kbd> to select all of the linked vertices and use the regular tools to edit, grab, size, rotate, etc.

[image]

[image]

---

As an alternative you can export the UV map as image and use it as reference to position the image so that it matches the UVs in an image editing app, then re-import the image and it should match the geometry.

Comment: Thank you for that I will try both. Looking at your model though I think I have constructed mine incorrectly. you have one continuous section for the roof whereas mine is split into about 4 sections, also you have both outside and inside textured? did you just use solidify to obtain that?

Comment: You did not provide a model, so I made a basic one... in any case the point is to demonstrate the workflow, not to do the model for you.